# How to turn ON/OFF an XmlWriter Indent property?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xmlwriter, xmltextwriter

I would like to turn ON/OFF the `Indent` property of a `XmlWriter` when I need it, to be able to write with this formatting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Songs>
  <Song><Name>My Song 1.mp3</Name><Year>2007</Year></Song>
  <Song><Name>My Song 2.mp3</Name><Year>2009</Year></Song>
  <Song><Name>My Song 3.mp3</Name><Year>2008</Year></Song>
</Songs>
```

The problem is I don't know how to modify the property, I've read in other SO question that is not possibly to set this property more than once... but... if using a `XmlTextWriter` instead an `XmlWriter` I can turn on/off the Indentation whenever i want, and notice that a `XmlTextWriter` is from Framework 2.0 so I can not believe that there is no way to modify the Indent property since the Class `XmlWriter`is much more current than the `XmlTextWriter`.

I would not use the `XmlTextWriter` instead of the `XmlWriter` just because the `XmlWriter` could become totally obsolete on future days, I preffer to use the logic of Framework current classes and to not base my code on old Classes.

Also I would not to do tricky things like "disable Indent and wrtie newlines with the WriteString method", because that will throws me exceptions at certains lines.

To clarify, I just would to turn on/off the indent property of an `XmlWriter` or a devired and working way to turn on/off indent whenever I want, but not any other thing that I won't do.

Here is the Code, it throws an exception when I attempt to modify the Indent property saying that is only read property, but like I've said, I can do it in a `XmlTextWriter` so... this seems too strange.

```
Dim xmlsettings As XmlWriterSettings = _
    New XmlWriterSettings() With { _
        .Indent = True, _
        .Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default}

Dim Xml As XmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlfile, xmlsettings)

Private Sub Write_SongInfo_Node(ByVal xml As XmlWriter,
                  ByVal Name As String, _
                  ByVal Year As String)

    xml.WriteStartElement("Song")

    xml.Settings.Indent = False

    xml.WriteStartElement("Name")
    xml.WriteString(Name)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Year")
    xml.WriteString(Year)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.Settings.Indent = True

    xml.WriteEndElement()

    ' xml.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why does the formatting of the `xml` matter?

Comment: @flindeberg arguably, you can shave some file size off by excluding the newlines and tabs but realistically, if you are having to optimise your xml that much, xml is the wrong technology.

Comment: @Gusdor In that case, why not set `XmlWriterSettings.Indent` to `false` and leave it there? I was wondering in this specific case, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XmlWriterSettings** is applied for whole writer at once when you create your writer instance and than it switches to read-only mode. There is only one possible way to switch this mode off - use **XmlWriterSettings.Reset()** method but I'm not sure that it can help you.
**XmlTextWriter** have got own formatting options for indentation and it checks them on each element writing step. In other words **XmlTextWriter** writes indents using own functional and doesn't use xmlwriter indentation properties.
So there is only one working decision for you - implement custom logic for elements writing in which you can:

- override default behavior, e.g. check elements name (like "Song") and omit useless indent symbols
- switch off XmlWriter indents (`XmlWriterSettings.Indent = false` ) and add your own method which will write indents manually when you need it

Answer (score 1):

You can not set XmlWriter's indent setting. but you can pass the xmlSetting object to `Write_SongInfo_Node` procedure and set `xmlSetting .Indent = True  or False`
hope it works.

Regards,