# c# Serialize xml node with different XmlWriterSettings than rest of object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to serialize an object as xml, but I need one of the elements and children elements of it to be serialized differently. The xml must be indented, but only a specific node (and its children) must be in 1 line.

so for example

```
<root>
<a>
    <b><c>value</c></b>
</a>
```

root and a are serialized with indentation, but b and c are all in one line

thanks

Comment: Already answered -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543160/1235106

Comment: genius mate, I guess my searching skills need some work